# React native flatlist inverted onscrollbegin runs every time I scrol

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use onScrollBegin on my flatlist. But everytime I make scroll the function runs. I only want to run this function when I am at the top, not everytime I scroll.

```
import *  as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, Image, Dimensions, Platform, FlatList, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { messages } from '../utils/mockChat';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
import { openModalImage } from '../redux/slice/chat/chatSlice';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('screen');

function propsEqual(prevProp, nextProp) {
  if(prevProp.id === nextProp.id) {
    return true;
  }
}

const Item = React.memo(({ global_user_id, id, type, render, allDates, name, user_id, reciever, text, images, video, sending, pending, read, date }) => {
  const dateNum = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  return (
    <View style={s.item}>

      <View style={s.itemContainer}>
        <View style={global_user_id === user_id ? s.ownerText : s.reciever_text}>
          <Text style={s.text}>{ text }</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}, propsEqual);

const userState = state => state.user.userID;

const modalState = state => state.chatSlice.modalImage;


const Chat = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { image } = route.params;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const modalSec = useSelector(modalState);

  const userID = useSelector(userState);

  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState(generateItems(messages));

  const modalR = React.useRef(null);
  const timerCloseModal = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
     modalSec && modalR.current.open();
  }, [modalSec]);

  const dates = new Set();

  function renderDate(date) {
    dates.add(moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
    return (
      <Text style={{color: '#333', fontSize: 12}}>{moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}</Text>
    )
  }

  const showFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View style={s.footerContainer}>
        <TextInput style={{height: 50, width: '100%', padding: 20}} />
      </View>
    )
  };

  const rowRenderer = ({ item }) => {

    return (
      <Item 
        item={item}
        id={item.id}
        allDates={dates} 
        render={(date) => renderDate(date)} 
        global_user_id={userID} 
        name={item.name} 
        user_id={item.user_id} 
        reciever={item.reciever} 
        text={item.text} 
        images={item.images} 
        video={item.video} 
        sending={item.sending} 
        pending={item.pending} 
        read={item.read} 
        type={item.type}
        date={item.date} />
    )
  };

  const closeModalImage = React.useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(openModalImage());
  }, [dispatch, modalR]);

  return (
    <View style={s.container}>

      <FlatList
        data={message}
        keyExtractor={i => i.id.toString()}
        renderItem={rowRenderer}
        initialNumToRender={10}
        onScrollBeginDrag={() => {
          console.log('s');


       //   setMessage(items);

        }}
        extraData={message}
        ListHeaderComponent={showFooter}
        inverted
      />
    </View>
  )
};

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  modal: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    borderRadius: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    maxHeight: 500,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height: 250,
    width: width * 0.8,
    marginVertical: 12
  },
  ownerText: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },
  reciever_text: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
  }
});

export default Chat;
```

How can I fix it, that I can only scroll if I am on the top? I use inverted so its hard for me, to know where is the top position. I am very thankful for your help

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `onEndReached` prop.
The `onEndReached` function calls every time you reach the end of a list.
[official doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached)